# How to convert string from win1250 to utf-8 in php?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Question this is marked as duplicate of doesnt answers to windows1250

No this question isn't answered all over internet.

The already answered question had database problem, 
mine is not even connected to database at point of this problem.

I have document in windows1250 and I need to find some string, I can supply only in UTF-8.

How do I encode from win-1250 to utf-8?

```
PHP convert string from windows-1250 to utf-8
```

I've tried iconv but maybe I tried wrong, because it just got me false.

What's the proper way encoding this in php7 on linux?

Comment: Your question title says "in javascript" but your tags say "php". You need to pick one.

Comment: "I've tried iconv but maybe I tried wrong, because it just got me false." — You need to provide a [mcve] when you have problems with your code.

Comment: I don't have problem with code, I have problem with encoding, that can be solved with any code...

Comment: You said you tried to fix it with iconv. Presumably, you wrote code then.

Comment: .... Which doesn't work, I'm not here for debging...

Comment: OK, obvious answer: `iconv('WINDOWS-1250', 'UTF-8', $str)`. I presume you have tried that. If so, *why exactly* "didn't it work"?

Comment: It returned false... and throwed some invalid character error.